# Why are a visual studio project's command-line settings stored per user? Is it OK to check-in (and share) a .user setting file?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, command-line, msbuild

We're creating an application that understands some command-line parameters.   There are some default's we would like to supply on the command-line when debugging, and these are easily set in the project settings [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298708/debugging-with-command-line-parameters-in-visual-studio).

The thing is visual studio stores these settings in a *.csproj.**user** file, and the default settings for integrated source control do not check-in *.**user** files.   We would like to just have these default command-line parameters in everyone's IDE when debugging this project.

Often (but not always) when visual studio guides you into doing things a certain way it is for good reason.  We probably don't want to just check-in someone's .csproj.**user** file... right?

This question is has a few parts:

- Why does Visual Studio store this
  particular setting per user?
- Is there a way to alter this behavior?  - Would doing so bring bad juju?
- Under these circumstances is it OK to check-in and share a **.user** file?
- Is there a better way to accomplish what we are
  trying to do here?

Thank you -

Comment: Seven years later, it still works the same way. While most project properties are stored in the `*.vcxproj` file, local debugger command arguments are stored in `*.vcxproj.user`. Give Microsoft points for consistency.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Maybe you could alter the program to optionally read its parameters from a configuration file as well as from the command-line (and then check-in a copy of that configuration file).

Comment: Good point.  This meets the same need and bypasses the issue.

Comment: Putting the default debugging command-line options into a .config file bypasses the issue but also forces in new behavior that may not have been wanted (we can live with it in this case.)  

In general I now see that relying on default debugging command-line parameters across the team and in source control is a bad thing.  It adds wrinkles to the CI (auto) builds and unit tests.  We are  effectively making "debug" parameters into a source artifact... not good.

So in general, the best answer is: "Don't do that - find another way" and in this case a .config file is fine.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I would not recommend checking in the user file because, as you said, this is per user.  If someone checks out your "default" user file and then makes any personalized configuration changes, those will be reflected back in the user file and (most likely) will be reflected in the source control.

If you want someone to set command-line parameters for debugging, I would adjust the project file to include these - don't include them in the user file.  (It is okay to check in the .proj file, and I typically do for my team projects.)

Comment: I have seen some very confused developers that did not realize that the .user file was in source control (or didn't know what it was for).

Comment: So if manually "merge" the xml that supplies the command-line parameters in the .user settings file with the main project file... will that do what I am hoping... or just mangle things?

Comment: @Jason: How would you adjust the project file to contain command line parameters?

Comment: I think I misread part of your post. I still stick to not checking in the .user file. I have to agree with your first bulleted point...no clue why Visual Studio does this. I just assumed that it went into the project file since that is how it is for a project I am working on.  A better alternative may be to document the settings and let each user specify where those settings are located.  Or, provide an initial config file that the users can just copy into their workspace.

Comment: "adjust the project file to include these" - how? By manual editing?

Comment: @thomthom and sbi - See this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/1ktzfy9w(v=vs.100).aspx and this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/298713/132528

Comment: @JasCav - did those link describe how to set the debugger properties per project instead of per user? From what I gathered they described where the settings where - but not how to avoid them ending up in the per-user setting.

Comment: @thomthom - I have always gone through the project settings and (I am looking at the raw .proj file right now) - all those settings are in the project file. (I'm using VS2013.) So...maybe something changed between 2010 and 2013 in how those settings were stored...

Comment: Hmm.. I'm using VS2013 as well and I found the debugger settings to be put in the .user file. Which I found to be very odd. I manually copied and pasted the settings and that worked though.