# How to set the default value for Debugging Command in Visual Studio project properties

Tags: visual-studio

As mentioned in [Why are a visual studio project's command-line settings stored per user? Is it OK to check-in (and share) a .user setting file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363540/why-are-a-visual-studio-projects-command-line-settings-stored-per-user-is-it-o) the Debugging properties are stored in the .user file which is normally ignored by source control.

I have changed the "Linker" -> "General" -> "Output File":

[image]

...which is stored in the project file which is under source control. I need to change the "Debugging" -> "Command" to match, but again, this is stored in the .user file which is not under source control.

Where does the default value come from? Here it is "$(TargetPath)":

[image]

I can change the value locally and it works, but when someone else clones my repo, builds, and runs it in debug, it cannot find the file because their local setting is the default.

This is a c++ project generating an .exe file and I am using VS Enterprise 2017, in case that is relevant.