# Command Line argument option not working on Visual C++ 2008

Tags: debugging, visual-c++, command-line, command-line-arguments

I am trying to pass command line parameters in Debug mode in one VC++ 2008 solution as described here [Debugging with command-line parameters in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298708/debugging-with-command-line-parameters-in-visual-studio). The thing is that somehow actually VC++ is not passing the parameteres because I always get 1 for "argc" variable. Is anything else that should be enabled or what could prevent VC++ passing the parameter?

In my configuration, under the Debug profile, in the Debuggin option of the project holding the "main" function I added the Command Arguments option as: "-c myconfigfile.txt".

Thank you very much in advance!!!

Comment: I forgot I set up a "Hello World!" test passing command line arguments and it works. By the way the main function is defined like this: int main(int argc, char *argv[]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. It was quite stupid thing in fact. The thing is that the project with the "main" file was not set as start-up project.