# Passing command line arguments in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, command-line-arguments

I am working on a C project and can not figure out how to pass command line arguments to my main function in Visual Studio 2010 Express Edition. I want to debug - how do these command line arguments work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Debugging with command-line parameters in Visual Studio.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298708/debugging-with-command-line-parameters-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 225, accepted):

- Right click your project in Solution Explorer and select Properties from the menu
- Go to Configuration Properties -> Debugging
- Set the Command Arguments in the property list.

[image: Adding Command Line Arguments]

Comment: @Andrew Cooper and what if we have 2 argument ? do we need to seprate then with `;` , and we set the path in the normal way like we did in c++ ?

Comment: @Ahmad - No.  Just type the arguments in like you would on the command line.  ie. separated by spaces.

Comment: Is there any way to enter them into the terminal if it's run as a terminal application?

Comment: @ChrisZhang I assume you mean a Console Application, and the answer is No.

Comment: @Andrew Cooper Can you tell me plz  how to pass multiple arguments in VS

Comment: @Frankenstein - Just add them as you would on the command line, separated by spaces

Comment: @AndrewCooper yes that what i have done but i'm unable to run it under VS however i can run it from command line : please view http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35196376/how-to-pass-multiple-commands-arguments-in-visual-studio

Comment: @alex yes. It's free-form text. It should be able to take any argument string you'd have on the command line

Answer (score 32):

Under Project->Properties->Debug, you should see a box for Command line arguments (This is in C# 2010, but it should basically be the same place)

Comment: Thankyou ! I picked the other guy's answer because he was the first one to answer !

Comment: @AlexHart   Can you tell me plz  how to pass multiple arguments in VS ?

Answer (score 13):

Visual Studio 2015:

`Project` `=>` Your Application `Properties`. Each argument can be separated using space. If you have a space in between for the same argument, put double quotes as shown in the example below.

[image]

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if(args == null || args.Length == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please specify arguments!");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(args[0]);     // First
                Console.WriteLine(args[1]);     // Second Argument
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Right click on **Project Name**.
2. Select **Properties** and click.
3. Then, select **Debugging** and provide your enough argument into **Command Arguments** box.

**Note:**

- Also, check **Configuration** type and **Platform**.

[image: img]

After that, Click **Apply** and **OK**.

Answer (score 0):

**Visual Studio** e.g. 2019
In general be aware that the selected Platform (e.g. x64) *in the configuration 
Dialog* is the the same as the Platform You intend to debug with!
(see picture for explanation)

Greetings
mic
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8RL0.png)

Answer (score 0):

**For Visual Studio 2022 - for console application**

1. Right-click on Project, click Properties
2. Expand Debug -> Click on General (option)
3. Click on Open Debug Launch profiles UI
4. Pass the parameter in value place.

[image: screenshot from VS 2022]