# I can't understand why this program keeps crashing

Tags: c

this program keeps crashing instead of letting me input arguments, why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    int shift = atoi(argv[1]);
    char message[256];
    strcpy(message, argv[2]);
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(message); i++) {
        printf("%c", message[i] + shift);
    }
    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

I am using codeblocks. But I also tried to run it with Notepad++. After I compiled it and when I run it it simply crashes: Name.exe has stopped working. Shouldn't it ask me to input arguments on command line?

Comment: On which line does it crash?

Comment: in what way is it crashing? what debugging information do you have?

Comment: If you psss zero or one arguments on the command line, you are likely to crash.  If your second arg is longer than 256 bytes, you are likely to crash.

Comment: Please add an `if (argc != 3) { fprintf(stderr, "invalid number of arguments, expected 3, got %d\n", argc); abort(); }` before the call to `atoi(argv[1])`. If you get the error message, then you called the program with the wrong number of arguments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A program can't possibly crash before you enter the arguments, because you need to enter the arguments **before** the program starts.

That is: you don't run your program like this:

```
Program.exe
12
hello
```

you need to run it like this:

```
Program.exe 12 hello
```

If you are using an IDE(you probably do), you need to configure your IDE to add the arguments. How to do that depends on which IDE you use. I assume you use Visual Studio - here is how to do it in Visual Studio: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3697320/794380