# Loading and displaying image using opencv in vs2012

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012

---

Thanks for all the replies!
I've added the ..\wavFile.wav in the command argument.

But I still cant use the command window.
It still pops up and close immediately.
Maybe its because I use the console application to run this program?
Or are there other reasons?

---

I am new to opencv and I tried the following code to load and display an image
(using visual studio 2012)
I ran it using the debug mode,  but I always get a window shows that
Usage: display_image ImageToLoadAndDisplay,and the window close immediately
(seems like argc is always equal to 2?)
The window wont stay there and wait for a command to load my image.

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
   if( argc != 2)
    {
      cout <<" Usage: display_image ImageToLoadAndDisplay" << endl;
      return 0;
    }
    Mat image;
    image = imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);   // Read the file

    if(! image.data )                         // Check for invalid input
    {
     cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
     return -1;
    }
    cvNamedWindow( "Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );// Create a window for display.
    imshow( "Display window", image );                   // Show our image inside it.
    waitKey(0);                                          // Wait for a    keystroke in the window
    return 0;
 }
```

Might be a really stupid question but I really cant figure it out for a long time.
Hope someone can help me! THANKS A LOT!

Comment: If you're seeing the text, argc is obviously not 2. Step through your code using your debugger and find where it is actually failing.

Comment: Seems like you did not pass the argument, did u??

Comment: If you don't know anything about argc,argv then remove if part and rewrite imread("C:\\address\\lena.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing command line arguments in Visual Studio 2010?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697299/passing-command-line-arguments-in-visual-studio-2010)

Comment: I put ./displayimg img.jpg in the command argument but it still dont work

Comment: img.jpg is in the same directory as vcproj file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Right click your project in Solution Explorer and select Properties from the menu
- Go to Configuration Properties -> Debugging
- Set the Command Arguments in the property list.
  [image]

source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/3697320/4499919

OR

The [Mozilla.org FAQ on debugging Mozilla on Windows](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Debugging_Mozilla_on_Windows_FAQ) is of interest here.

In short, the Visual Studio debugger can be invoked on a program from the command line, allowing one to specify the command line arguments when invoking a command line program, directly on the command line.

This looks like the following for Visual Studio 8 or 9

devenv /debugexe 'program name' 'program arguments'
It is also possible to have an [explorer action](http://www.olegsych.com/2007/08/debugexe-command-line-switch-in-visual-studio/) to start a program in the Visual Studio debugger.

source : [Debugging with command-line parameters in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298708/debugging-with-command-line-parameters-in-visual-studio)

OR

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24202291/opencv-imread-from-command-line-argv1

Comment: If the answer to this question is found in an older question, then this is a duplicate. You should mark as duplicate instead of copying other answers.  (I'm not downvoting you because you correctly give credit to the authors of the answers.)

Comment: I put the ..\wavFile.wav in the command argument but it still reacts the same

Comment: .wav is a audio format file , opencv is for image processing

Comment: @Miki i will take care about this next time :) ,thnx