# Passing Command Line Argument to Button Text

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, command-line-arguments

I have created a simple Application to notify a user of something that is happening. It consists of a single button that when a command line is passed to it, it will display that as the text property of the button. What I want to accomplish is that if no command line arguments are specified, it will display a default message. I'm new to C# so be gentle... Here is what i have so far.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string[] passedinargs = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

        if (passedinargs == null)
        {
            btnNotify.Text = "Please Start from Command Line";
        }
        else
        {
            btnNotify.Text = passedinargs[1];
        }
```

When ran, this Execption is given:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in Notify.exe

with `btnNotify.Text = passedinargs[1];` highlighted.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You are probably trying to access first argument, they array starts with `0` index, try `btnNotify.Text = passedinargs[0];` *Remember that the first argument is the filename of the executable*

Comment: Otherwise, make sure that you are passing the command line arguments either through command line or [through visual studio debugger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697299/passing-command-line-arguments-in-visual-studio-2010)

Comment: When just using `btnNotify.Text = passedinargs[1];` without an if statement (and a arg is passed) it works just fine.

Comment: I don't believe passedinargs will ever be null, since it will include at least the executable name in [0], so that null test won'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What I want to accomplish is that if no command line arguments are specified, it will display a default message.

That suggests you should check for the length of the arguments with the `Length` property. So something like:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

    btnNotify.Text = args.Length < 2
        ? "Please provide an argument on the command line"
        : args[1]; // First command-line argument.
}
```

I'm pretty sure that `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` will never return null. If you find it does, you could use `args == null || args.Length < 2` in the condition.

Comment: Jon, Thanks for the help. Works Great!

Answer (score 1):

***passedinargs*** is an array that may contain 1 or more elements.
The first element (which is ***passedinargs[0]***) is always the executable file name and the rest (0 or more) are the remaining command line arguments.
If you want to use ***passedinargs[1]*** (which is the first command line argument AFTER the executable file name), you need to verify that it exists by checking ***passedinargs.Length***.

So, my suggestion is to modify your condition and query:

```
if (passedinargs == null || passedinargs.Length < 2)
{
    btnNotify.Text = "Please Start from Command Line";
} 
...
```

Comment: If it always have element [0] as the name of the exe then checking for null is always false.