# How to pass multiple commands arguments in visual studio?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013, command-line-arguments, visual-studio-debugging, lzma

I am working on a compession/decompression project using the LZMA SDK.

The main program contains some arguments that I must use to run the application

To run it from the command line, I use :

```
./LzmaUtil.exe e input.elf output.elf
```

I'm using VS 2013 , so i have added `e in.elf out.elf` to the commands arguments, I rebuild the project (the executable file in generated) but nothing seems to happen when I press RUN.

Note that I have the `input.elf` in the debug folder were the `.exe` is present there, and the , the flag `e` is used to compress the file and `output.elf` is the compressed file.

[image: Issue VS 2013]

The main function contains :

```
int MY_CDECL main(int numArgs, const char *args[])
{
    char rs[800] = { 0 };
    int res = main2(numArgs, args, rs);
    fputs(rs, stdout);
    return res;
}
```

The complete source code is available at : http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html

**Debugging :**

With no arguments at all I get :

```
The program '[5284] LzmaUtil.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

With the arguments I have mentionned I get :

```
The program '[5284] LzmaUtil.exe' has exited with code 1 (0x1).
```

so something is happenning !!!

With breakpoint at the main I get :

```
numArgs 4   int
args    0x007eaca8 {0x007eacbc "E:\\1PFE\\LZMA\\LzmaUtil\\Debug\\LzmaUtil.exe"} const char * *
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What happens if you put a breakpoint at the beginning of `main`? What happens if the _Command Arguments_ field iks empty?

Comment: @MichaelWalz thanks , I added the debugginf part , it seems that the arguments are well recognized because the variable args contains 4 but i didn't understand the line below

Comment: `args[0]` points to `"E:\\1PFE\\LZMA\\LzmaUtil\\Debug\\LzmaUtil.exe"`, `args[1]` points to  `"e"`, `args[2]` points to `"in.elf"` etc. Pretty basic C stuff.

Comment: @MichaelWalz yes i know this but i don't get any output !!!

Comment: you did not give the complete code, the link goes to LZMA SDK.

Comment: @Frankenstein if `main` receives the command line arguments correctly, then the problem is somewhere in `main2`.

Comment: @MichaelWalz  don't thing that there is a problem in the source code , that's because when running the generated application from command line it works just fine

Comment: @Frankenstein well, step into `main2` and you'll find out. This should be too hard.

Comment: ok let's see `c = args[1][0];`  using the warch i get `'Ì'` as a value !!! but it must be `e`

Comment: @Frankenstein and after char *p` = args[1]`, what does `p`point to ?

Comment: `  Read 0x00cfa080 {lzmaUtil.exe!FileSeqInStream_Read(void *, void *, unsigned int *)} int (void *, void *, unsigned int *) *`
 but for `*p` it tell me that it's undefined

Comment: @kennyzx the source code is very long ! yes the LZMA SDK contains the complete source code

Comment: Does the output window show anything useful? (View -> Output -> Show output from: Debug)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output was empty because I had put the file in the debug folder which is the same folder as the executable.

However, when I put the file in the parent directory (or the solution folder), it finally worked.

Comment: You should make a well formatted answer for your question.