# C# error in Visual Studio 2017 for a Console Project and cannot find debugging options

Tags: c#

I am a complete beginner in C# and this is kind of my first project.
So what I am trying to do is, make a console app and directly put input in the app for displaying but I am facing some difficulties in doing so.

Problem 1:  [Getting an error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3QFA.jpg)

Problem 2: [Cant find the debugging options under configuration properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/127qD.jpg)

Please find the attached images of the errors.

Comment: Please create separate Stack Overflow questions for each question you have.

Comment: Check this question and do the necessary input validation as it is shown in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697299/passing-command-line-arguments-in-visual-studio-2010

Comment: Your code is short and the error message is simple, so it would be great if you could include them in your question rather than linking them as images. It makes it much easier for answerers to do their stuff.

Comment: Anyway, that said: problem 1 is simple, because the error message tells you everything you need to know: the args array is empty, so even index 0 is out of range.

Comment: Welcome! Please do not post screenshots of your code and/or error messages (something to read: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2819245), [An image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) and [Pictures of exceptions are not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/)).

Comment: Also, you are never too fresh, never too green and never too much of a beginner to not dip your toes into the debugger of Visual Studio ([Learn to debug using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/getting-started-with-the-debugger)) ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem 1: The error message is occurring because you aren't passing any arguments to your application, so the array has no elements. Accessing index 0 of an empty array will throw the exception you see.

Problem 2: Looks like you're selecting the solution's properties instead of your project's properties. Instead:

- Right click on the application (not the solution) in your solution
  explorer. In your case this is the bolded ConsoleApp2
- Select 'properties'
- In the tab that opens, select 'Debug'
- Enter
  something into the "Application Arguments" box

Answer (score 1):

## To Problem 1

You do not pass any args thus `args[0]` leads to the non-existing first element which then correctly throws the exception

## To Problem 2

You selected the solution. To change properties of a project (which you probably want to do to add some argument to your debuging session so **Problem 1** goes away), you need to select the actual project, not the solution.