# How do I start a program with arguments when debugging?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-debugging

I want to debug a program in Visual Studio 2008. The problem is that it exits if it doesn't get arguments. This is from the main method:

```
if (args == null || args.Length != 2 || args[0].ToUpper().Trim() != "RM") 
{
    Console.WriteLine("RM must be executed by the RSM.");
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit program...");
    Console.Read();
    Environment.Exit(-1);
}
```

I don't want to comment it out and and then back in when compiling. How can I start the program with arguments when debugging? It is set as the StartUp Project.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing command line parameters with Visual Studio C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475887/passing-command-line-parameters-with-visual-studio-c-sharp)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Debugging with command-line parameters in Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298708/debugging-with-command-line-parameters-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 215, accepted):

Go to `Project-><Projectname> Properties`. Then, click on the `Debug` tab. Then:

**If you're using Visual Studio 2022**

Continue by clicking `Open debug launch profiles UI`. Fill in your arguments in the textbox labeled `Command line arguments`.

**If you're using a version before Visual Studio 2022**

The `Command Line Arguments` textbox is available on the Debug tab. Fill your arguments in the textbox.

Comment: The arguments can (must?) be filled into the `Command line arguments` space separated (like you would do, using the command line). I'm not sure if there are other ways, but maybe you can add this to your answer.

Comment: I have been looking for this answer for a week! Thank you!

Comment: Don't forget speech marks around command arguments containing spaces, that caught me out.

Comment: Is it possible to use named parameters for when using libraries like command line parser? e.g. How can I pass something like `-url https://google.com -p pass -u user`?

Answer (score 62):

I would suggest using the [directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx) like the following:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
#if DEBUG
            args = new[] { "A" };
#endif

            Console.WriteLine(args[0]);
        }
```

Good luck!

Comment: Both good answers, I like this more only because it is easier to change or reference (although it is not necessarily a hassle going through properties :p, maybe an extra mouse click or so)

Comment: I agree with Homam's Solution. Though for a small program , setting the Project Properties -> Debug Tab's Command line arguments is a more direct and easy way to debug, for large applications using Directives are more helpful and elegant.

Comment: Both solutions are perfect. but, I kind of prefer the solution by Homam. Its elegant does not need to tinker with the project setings which one may forget to take care of. On a seconf thought one may also forget the code changes made but they are at least "visible".

Comment: Omho this answer is THE answer. It is a tedious job to edit the project settings every time you want to debug with a new set of command line parameters. When it's written like this, you can just simply write down all the test cases you want to check and just toggle the comments on each to activate it. Much faster and proves especially useful if you're suddenly in front of a Visual Studio in a different language (not the one you are used to work with), which is exactly my case and although I know the language, the translation is awful and even a native speaker can't deal with it properly. :D

Answer (score 6):

My suggestion would be to use Unit Tests.

In your application do the following switches in `Program.cs`:

```
#if DEBUG
    public class Program
#else
    class Program
#endif
```

and the same for `static Main(string[] args)`.

Or alternatively use [Friend Assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/friend-assemblies?tabs=csharp) by adding

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("TestAssembly")]
```

to your `AssemblyInfo.cs`.

Then create a unit test project and a test that looks a bit like so:

```
[TestClass]
public class TestApplication
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMyArgument()
    {
        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            Console.SetOut(sw); // this makes any Console.Writes etc go to sw

            Program.Main(new[] { "argument" });

            var result = sw.ToString();

            Assert.AreEqual("expected", result);
        }
    }
}
```

This way you can, in an automated way, test multiple inputs of arguments without having to edit your code or change a menu setting every time you want to check something different.

Comment: wow, the question is about providing args to the debug-session and you mention unit-tests? How is this related to the question?

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain This might be an abuse of unit tests, but it's a clever workaround for VS lacking easily selectable launch profiles. I've abused unit tests in a similar way to selectively seed different tables of a database.

Answer (score 6):

I came to this page because I have sensitive information in my command line parameters, and didn't want them stored in the code repository.  I was using System Environment variables to hold the values, which could be set on each build or development machine as needed for each purpose.  Environment Variable Expansion works great in Shell Batch processes, but not Visual Studio.

*Visual Studio  Start Options:*

[image: Visual Studio Start Options]

However, Visual Studio wouldn't return the variable value, but the name of the variable.

*Example of Issue:*

[image: Example of Error in Visual Studio]

My final solution after trying several here on S.O. was to write a quick lookup for the Environment variable in my Argument Processor.  I added a check for % in the incoming variable value, and if it's found, lookup the Environment Variable and replace the value.  This works in Visual Studio, and in my Build Environment.

```
foreach (string thisParameter in args)
            {
                if (thisParameter.Contains("="))
                {
                    string parameter = thisParameter.Substring(0, thisParameter.IndexOf("="));
                    string value = thisParameter.Substring(thisParameter.IndexOf("=") + 1);

                    if (value.Contains("%"))
                    {   //Workaround for VS not expanding variables in debug
                        value = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(value.Replace("%", ""));
                    }
```

This allows me to use the same syntax in my sample batch files, and in debugging with Visual Studio.  No account information or URLs saved in GIT.

*Example Use in Batch*

[image: Batch File Example]

Answer (score 3):

for .NET Core console apps you can do this 2 ways - from the launchsettings.json or the properties menu.

Launchsettings.json

[image]

or right click the project > properties > debug tab on left

see "Application Arguments:"

- this is " " (space) delimited, no need for any commas. just start typing. each space " " will represent a new input parameter.
- (whatever changes you make here will be reflected in the launchsettings.json file...)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For **Visual Studio Code**:

- Open `launch.json` file
- Add args to your configuration:

> "args": ["some argument", "another one"],