# Quickly enter command-line parameters for Visual Studio debugging?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I want to change my command-line arguments and then debug my executable.

With the default Visual Studio UI, this takes me several tortuous mouse and keyboard actions:

> Project ... right click ... Configuration Properties ... Debugging ... Command Arguments ... *type args* ... ENTER ... F5

Is there a way to make this common action as easy as other common operations, for example, searching all files for a pattern which goes:

> CNTL+SHIFT+F ... *type search pattern* ... ENTER

For example, is there an way to create a custom edit box to allow quick access to the debug command-line arguments?  Or a way to have a key-binding pop up a simple "debug dialog" where the args can be entered and debugging started directly?  e.g.

> ALT+F5 ... *type args* ... ENTER

I am using C++ and Visual Studio 2010 Express.  Thanks!

Comment: Seems like you could write a macro for this. Record it, then edit it to prompt instead of using the typed text. Assign a hotkey, and you're pretty close?

Comment: @CraigStuntz -- The macro recorder won't record anything you do inside modal dialog boxes.

Comment: It's also worth considering a [different approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791140/how-do-i-start-a-program-with-arguments-when-debugging); see Øyvind's solution using compiler directives.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Macro below should help. Open "Tools->Macros->Macro Explorer", then create new module, edit it, and copy-paste code below. Required command is SetCommandArgsProperty. UI is not nice, but it works (VS 2005, I hope this will also work in VS 2010). Then add any shortcut you like to run this macro.

Here are some details:

- Find startup project
- Select it active configuration and find property with name "CommandArguments"
- Create edit box with the current value in it
- Update property if OK is selected

  ```
  Sub SetCommandArgsProperty()
      Dim newVal As Object
      newVal = InputValue(GetCommandArgsPropertyValue())
      If TypeOf newVal Is String Then
          SetCommandArgsProperty(newVal)
      End If
  End Sub

  Function InputValue(ByVal defaultText As String)
      Dim frm As New System.Windows.Forms.Form
      Dim btn As New System.Windows.Forms.Button
      Dim edit As New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox

      edit.Text = defaultText
      edit.Width = 100

      btn.Text = "OK"
      btn.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK

      frm.Text = "Input command line properties"

      frm.Controls.Add(btn)
      btn.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Bottom

      frm.Controls.Add(edit)
      edit.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Top

      frm.Height = 80
      frm.Width = 300

      If frm.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
          Return edit.Text
      End If
      Return System.DBNull.Value
  End Function

  Function GetCommandArgsProperty() As EnvDTE.Property
      Dim solution As Solution
      Dim project As Project
      Dim sb As SolutionBuild
      Dim str As String
      Dim cm As ConfigurationManager
      Dim config As Configuration
      Dim properties As Properties
      Dim prop As EnvDTE.Property

      solution = DTE.Solution
      sb = solution.SolutionBuild
      For Each str In sb.StartupProjects
          project = solution.Item(str)
          cm = project.ConfigurationManager
          config = cm.ActiveConfiguration
          properties = config.Properties
          For Each prop In properties
              If prop.Name = "CommandArguments" Then
                  Return prop
              End If
          Next
      Next
  End Function

  Function GetCommandArgsPropertyValue()
      Return GetCommandArgsProperty().Value
  End Function

  Sub SetCommandArgsProperty(ByVal value As String)
      GetCommandArgsProperty().Value = value
  End Sub
  ```

Comment: Unfortunately I only have Visual Studio Express, so no macros.  But I like the soution.

Answer (score 11):

The extension CLIArgsMadeEasy 2010/2012 is a great little thing that puts the project's debug session's command line arguments right in a little text box on the visual studio toolbar, IMO, its alot easier and less tedious than using macros.

The Link
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8159cd7d-2c81-47f3-9794-a347ec1fba09?SRC=VSIDE

You can just type CLIArgsMadeEasy in your search box in the extensions manager which will find it fairly quickly in the gallery, thats how I installed it, if you need to know. Hope this helps!

Comment: +1 ATM this version will work with VS2010 only (don't get confused by the naming...). There's a VS2012 version available here though: http://n0n4m3.codingcorner.net/?p=214. It works but still has some issues.

Comment: Is there a version for VS2013?

Answer (score 5):

At least in Visual Studio 2012, you can use `Alt+F7` shortcut to directly access project properties.

Furthermore, the opened Property Pages normally remembers the last opened item, i.e. `Configuration Properties -> Debugging`.