# visual studio 2012 multiple -commands in command line arguments

Tags: visual-studio-2012

In visual studio 2012 it is possible on the debug-> start options to specify command line arguments. I am working on a powershell cmdlet so I'd like to be able to parse multiple commands into powershell. My arguments looks like this

```
-noexit -command add-pssnapin Registerv2.0 -command New-Token -command www.google.com
```

the problem is it is treating -command as 1 long string i.e -command "add-pssnapin Registerv2.0 -command New-Token -command www.google.com" rather then 3 seperae commands. Does anyone know how to change this:

edit
the results I am looking for is when I run the project

1. power shell opens
2. my snapin is registered
3. Call the cmdlet new-token
4. enter in the cmdlet parameters

Comment: Does putting them in quotes not work?

Comment: it would work if they were positional parameters. But each command needs to be on its own line in powershell.

Comment: [maybe this can help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460270/quickly-enter-command-line-parameters-for-visual-studio-debugging)

Comment: If you are trying to pass parameters from Visual studio then this might help. -> 1. Go to project properties -> 2. Go to Debug -> 3. Seperate commands with white space. i.e. par1=val1 par2=val2 par3=val3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you first want `add-pssnapin Registerv2.0` and then `New-Token` to be called, you should chain them in one command, like so:

```
-command "add-pssnapin Registerv2.0; New-Token"
```

If `New-Token` expects a parameter, you should pass it on the command line directly, instead of trying to simulate user input.

For example, `New-Item` would expect a list of paths and a type as input, both can also be supplied on the command line as parameters. Like so:

```
New-Item foo -type directory
```

So, how you would pass the value `www.google.com` to `New-Token` depends on the name of the parameter. But could look like:

```
-command "add-pssnapin Registerv2.0; New-Token -tokenName www.google.com"
```