# C# square program

Tags: c#, .net, arguments

I have problem in the following C# program. there is no error when a code it but when I debug it  put an exception that index is out of the range of array bound.

What is the problem here?

```
using System;
class secmain
{
    public static void squarearg(int i)
    {
        int m=i*i;
        Console.WriteLine("The Square of the argument is {0}",m);
    }
    static void Main(String[] param)
    {
     Console.WriteLine("this program will convert your string argument to int and display the square of the numbe");
     int k = Int32.Parse(param[0]);
      squarearg(k);
      }
}
```

Comment: areyou sure you have pass an argument?

Comment: try to pass a command line argument and the program should work.

Comment: I know this is only a simple application but may I also recommend that you give your variables meaningful names; 'i', 'm' and 'k' aren't very descriptive names, if this is educational, you may lose marks for that :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well debugging it *(normally)* won't get the [command line parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288457%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) in the `param` that is why you are getting the exception.

You need to run its executable from the command line and pass the parameter from there, something like on your dos prompt, *(cmd)*

```
C:\yourProjectPath\bin\debug> yourExecutable.exe 2
```

*(In above 2 is the command line argument that you will get in your `param[0]` as string)*

Or you can use `Console.ReadLine` to get value from the console and then process that instead of command line parameters.

If you want to pass the argument during the debug process then check this question: [How do I start a program with arguments when debugging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791140/how-do-i-start-a-program-with-arguments-when-debugging)

Go to project properties and specify Command line argument under debug tab in Command Line Argument text box, like the following image.

[image]

The above will give you result `4` for argument `2`

Answer (score 4):

If you click project properties, under the Debug section, just below the Build, you can pass in arguments.

It will look like so:

```
/client:"Someclient.exe" 1 2 3
```

Which means main argument `param` won't be empty i.e. `param.Count > 0`

Answer (score 1):

This is because of this statement
`int k = Int32.Parse(param[0]);` you are not passing any value during the runtime. And you are trying to use the value from `command-line argument`
This will guide you how to pass [command line argument in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288457%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Run your program this way

```
myfile.exe 125
```

Answer (score 1):

When using `param` it will expect that it was given in the command line. Try running it with something like "secmain.exe 4".
Or you can go to `Project Properties->Debug-> Start Options->Command line arguments` and enter a value there.

Answer (score 1):

```
int k = Int32.Parse(param[0]);
```

I assume the error is there.  You are not passing any parameters into the program.

You could do a check:

```
if (param.Length == 0)
{
   Console.WriteLine("No arguments have been passed into the program");
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664432(v=vs.71).aspx