# What is a good way of initializing a vector of char* from string literals?

Tags: c++, string, char, literals

Until C++11, one was able to write the following:

```cpp
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main_under_test(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    vector<char*> args {"--foo", "--bar"};

    return main_under_test(args.size(), args.data());
}
```

However, assigning a literal value to a non-`const` `char*` is not possible any longer.

Fortunately, since C++11, we have that `std::string::data()` is guaranteed to be null-terminated, so we can do the following:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main_under_test(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    vector<string> strArgs {"--foo", "--bar"};
    vector<char*> args;
    for (auto & strArg : strArgs) {
        args.push_back(strArg.data());
    }

    return main_under_test(args.size(), args.data());
}
```

However, while that works, it does not look great. Is there a better way to initialize a `vector` (or an array, for that matter) of non-`const` `char*` from literals?

Comment: please define "better". Why do you not use a `std::vector<std::string>` ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Because they need to call a function accepting `(int, char**)`, as implied by the examples.

Comment: Also maybe https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `However, assigning a literal value to a non-const char* is not possible any longer.` – actually one shouldn't ever have been doing so anyway. This legacy feature from C, now being dropped, was a loophole to introduce undefined behaviour for modifying string literals.

Comment: std::vector<std::string_view> is possible here. But your solution with std::vector<std::string> is not bad at all. That it doesn't look great is maybe because you come from a "C" background, in C++ this is totally fine and the `std::vector<char*>` looks suspicious (to me)

Comment: `int main_under_test(int argc, char const * const * const argv)` and `std::vector<char const *>` will work without issue.

Comment: @PepijnKramer what do you mean by "go C++ all the way"? Who am I am to change the definition of the signature of the `main` function used by practically all today's linkers?

Comment: @user7860670 yes, if changing another module's code was possible, that would work ;)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai I am not interested in a `vector<string>`, so a better solution would avoid using `#include <string>`, for instance. A better solution would likely also be shorter. (Both is true for the original code which no longer works.)

Comment: @bers no the main functions signature is what it is. I mean not to use "raw pointers" at all in your own code (as described in the ["C++ core guidelines"](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines))

Comment: Is this the about the signature of `main`, or  a third party API function, or a function in your own/company library? What are the post-conditions of the function? Is it going to modify the strings, or just happens to have the bad signature? The proper approach would be different in each case.

Answer (score 2):

In C++23:

```
std::vector<std::string> strings = {"--foo", "--bar"};
auto ptrs = strings
    | std::views::transform([](auto &s){return s.data();})
    | std::ranges::to<std::vector>();
```

Libstdc++ doesn't have `ranges::to` yet, but this works on libc++ and MSVC STL.

Sadly we can't pass `&std::string::data` directly to `transform`, since `data()` is overloaded.

Comment: You could `static_cast` it to the desired type to select a specific overload. However, the result ain’t pretty … (`std::views::transform(static_cast<char* (std::string::*)() noexcept>(&std::string::data))`). (Unrelated to downvote, of course)

Comment: @KonradRudolph Mhm, thought about that, but decided that I like a lambda more.

Comment: Yes, of course — the lambda is much more readable.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the canonical solution would be to use:

```
std::vector<char*> args { const_cast<char*>( "--foo" ),
                          const_cast<char*>( "--bar" ) }
```

The main use of `const_cast` is for compatibility with old interfaces, which don't use `const` where they should.

Note that this will not work if `main_under_test` actually tries to modify the `char`s in the args. If it is an actual `main`, it most likely doesn't, but if this is a possibility, you'll have to resort to copying the string literals in some way, or using them as initializers to a char[]. This will probably involve an explicit loop.

Comment: "Note that this will not work if `main_under_test` actually tries to modify the `char`s in the args." - yes, that would be undefined behavior. Hard to prevent that, though.

Comment: @bers Agreed. But if `main_under_test` is code that you've written, you know if it's the case. (Also, there are in practice only minimum ways that you can modify the strings; since they are C style strings, you cannot make them larger.)

Comment: There might be potential risk that, while not modifying now, co-workers (unaware of this approach) might change code so that it later on indeed does – breaking the test that way…

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `main_under_test` is what will in the future replace the current `main` function then it appears far more appropriate to me simply using a shell script (linux) or batch file (windows) – where you can modify the arguments on the fly without needing to recompile (!) – and just make the `main_under_test` function your true `main` function right now (so actually an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)…).

Still if you insist on your current approach then instead of creating pointers to string literals you might use these to initialise arrays:

```
char raw[][128] = { "--foo", "--bar" };
```

OK, now we have a 2D array – and that cannot just be converted to a pointer array, so in that case we need to do that on our own – in code, but that has to be written just one single time:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char raw[][128] = { "--foo", "--bar" }; // arbitrarily modifiable...

    char* args[std::size(raw) + 2] = { *argv }; // the executable name (!)
    char** a = args;
    for(auto& r : raw)
    {
        *++a = r;
    }
    *++a = nullptr; // argv is always null-terminated as well!

    return main_under_test(std::size(args) + 1, args);
}
```

Demonstration on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/xnvGvMxvh).

Will even work on old C++ standards (apart from having to replace `std::size` with the good old `sizeof` trick for pre-C++11…).

Yet another alternative would be simply casting const-ness away (`{ const_cast<char*>("literals") }`), but then you rely on `main_under_test` strictly promising not to modify the arguments, otherwise yielding undefined behaviour, so that approach is pretty less recommendable.

Comment: Think of `main_under_test` as the `main` function of another executable, which I test by linking against its `.obj` file (MSVC language, I guess). I love the benefit of calling my tests in Visual Studio with a debugger attached - that comfort is lost when starting a subprocess, I guess.

Comment: @bers Well, any even only halfway good IDE should come with means to provide command line arguments to the application being debugged! And indeed, even MSVS [does so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4791147/1312382) – probably better option...

Comment: Aconcagua sure. Any halfway good IDE, however, also has a test framework that you can start with the debugger attached to the test framework. And why would I want to copy each failing test's command line parameters into the project properties just to restart the debugger attached to the process started by the failing test?

Comment: @bers Well, that's all information that's been lacking so far... So you create dedicated executables for each test such that on failure you can debug them directly. Disadvantage, of course, is that your real sources need to be modified depending on being in test or not (-> renaming the `main` function when testing). Probably even greater disadvantage that you cannot modify parameters on the fly (would need to recompile). Could be an interesting idea to let the test framework generate such batch files, though no idea how flexible your framework is and if that's doable at all with it…

Comment: It's Microsoft's C++ VS Test framework: it builds dll files, not executables, and no, I do not have to rename any main function for testing. Beyond that, I think I'd rather not go into the details of test frameworks in comments to an answer to a question on string literals ... :)

Comment: @bers Just that it feels (felt?) a bit like an [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), thus digging a bit deeper… Though with your explanation it seems as if it's exactly what this test framework is proposing (apparently automatically doing the renaming under the hoods). Pretty unfortunate then that there isn't any direct support class for command line arguments (even from literals) – or have you possibly overlooked?

Comment: I feel you are seeing an XY-Problem where there is none. I have a `main` function that I want to call with fixed arguments. This happens to be from a test, but it doesn't really matter. Also, if you are not familiar with VSTest, at least please do not imply that I am not, either.

Comment: @bers Never implied you were not experienced with – sorry if you felt alike. Just tried to justify why I personally was asking further. Without knowing any context, it could easily have been a xy-problem, especially as it's a rather unusual way how this framework works ;)