# Easy way to run command line programs C++ - Windows 7

Tags: c++, command-line, cmd

I am trying to find an easier way to test my command line application. It has arguments so I run it from a command prompt. My process is this:

1. Build
2. Go to the output
3. Open command prompt
4. Change directory
5. Run it

There has to be an easier way not only to debug but to open a command prompt in the current folder.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: build environment? (i.e. Visual Studio, or something else)

Comment: @crashmstr Yes, Visual Studio 2010

Comment: Can't you just run it from VS?

Comment: How about this.  Open command prompt, navigate to output directory, build, run, modify, build, run, modify, build, run, modify, build, run, modify, build, run, modify, build, run, modify, build, run, modify, build, run, modify ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to the project properties, Debugging settings, you can set the working directory and parameters. If you use the same parameters all of the time, you can enter those in on that screen as well. Then just F5 or Ctrl+F5 to run.

Set a breakpoint at the end of the code to keep it from going away after it is done.

Comment: Or add a statement: `cin.ignore(1000000, "\n";` to have it pause until ENTER is pressed.

Answer (score 2):

See [Debugging with command-line parameters in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298708/debugging-with-command-line-parameters-in-visual-studio)

Alternatively, you should be able to use a shell script (or Python [os.system()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.system)) to automate some of those steps.

Comment: this quesiton seems a lot like a possible dublicate of what you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

To open a command prompt in the current directory using explorer, you can shift+right click->Open Command Window Here. That will save a little time.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Visual Studio, pressing F5 will run the code in the debugger, and Ctrl+F5 will run the code normally. Just remember to include a `cin.get()` statement at the end or the terminal window will close before you can read the output.

Other IDEs should have similar functions. Check in the Run or Debug menu.

EDIT: Sorry, didn't see that you're asking about running it with arguments. In VS, in Project Properties there are the Debugging settings. Within that, there is a field called Command Arguments. These will get passed to the application when you run it from within VS.

Answer (score 0):

In project properties under debugging you can set the command line arguments (and environment variables) when debugging,

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension called `PowerCommands for Visual Studio 2010` that can be installed from  `Tools -> Extension Manager`.  It includes a `Open Containing Folder` and `Open Command Prompt` functionality that gets added to your right-click menu in the Solution Explorer.