# Passing the filename as command line parameters in OpenCV

Tags: visual-c++, opencv, command-line-arguments

I want to know how to pass the filenames with their respective paths as command line arguements in OpenCV. I'am using Visaul C to develop my OpenCV project. Whenever I run the exe file created after building it in VS it generates error stating Unable to load from file.
I want to ask what is the way in which I can run the OpenCV project by passing required command line parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly then [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298708/debugging-with-command-line-parameters-in-visual-studio) about command-line parameters while debugging in VC++ answers it. Specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/298713/7531).