# debugging with visual studio using redirected standard input

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

I am debugging c++ console application with Visual studio. I exhausted of inserting the same input every time I debug this program. I would like to use the same input more times.

I do this without debugging in command line with command: Program.exe < 1.in

Is it possible to use debugging with standard input redirected from file???

I already tried looking in to procejt properties. I tried setting Command to $(TargetPath) < 1.in instead of $(TargetPath).
I also tried setting Command Arguments to < 1.in. Niether of these method worked.

I am using Visual Studio 2012. But this is probably same in all versions of studio.

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298708/debugging-with-command-line-parameters-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This is a supported debugging scenario.  You do have to make sure that the debugger can find the file.  Leave the Command setting at `$(TargetPath)`.  A possible value for the Command Arguments setting is:

```
 < "$(ProjectDir)test.txt"
```

if the input file "test.txt" is located in the project directory.  Or type the full path of the file to be sure.  The MSDN article that describes this feature is [available here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kcw4dzyf%28v=VS.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Notes:

The "Command line arguments" fields that worked for me was: `< test.txt` Where `test.txt` was in the `.../<solution>/<package>/bin/Debug/`

Remember to check your _exact_ filename

With a command line argument & standard in I had a "Command line arguments" field of: `-hello < test.txt`

Comment: This is a C++ question.  But sure, it works in a C# or VB.NET project as well.

Comment: In vscode arguments in launch.json should be separated:

            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/robot_strategy.exe",
            "args": ["<", "${workspaceFolder}/robot_strategy.in"],

Answer (score 2):

I just create a file called stdin.txt in the project
1) set the Build Action to Content
2) Copy to Ouput Directory: Copy if newer

Then when you build stdin.txt is copied to the same folder as the executable.

Then in project properties debug|command line arguements enter the following
  < stdin.txt

There is no need to use a path macro

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to mess with the the path you can `add` a `new file` with a right click on the `source files` folder in the `solution explorer` and then paste to it the content from the wanted file. And then change the command argument to the new file name.