# How to read from stdin in Visual Studio when using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, stdout, stdin

I've been working at a task for college for several hours now. I spent an hour doing the actual problem and the rest trying to achieve what I'm asking:

A python script needs to receive its input via stdin, preferably data that was redirected from a file (so I can test it), and it has to output the data to stdout in a way that I can see what it is (maybe redirect it to another file).

Please don't tell me that the Enterprise version of Visual Studio doesn't have way to feed a file data through stdin and print what comes out on stdout.

I understand how to do it internally, from the script, I just don't know where I put the data I want VS to send to stdin. I've opened the interactive terminal and started the debugger and cmd window waited for the input. Once I copied it in, nothing happened. I tried ctrl+D, still nothing.

What do I do?

Comment: You can modify your command line for running the program to include `< stdin.txt` where that's the name of the file you want to use as input. This isn't really a Python thing at all, more a Visual Studio thing. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043986/debugging-with-visual-studio-using-redirected-standard-input

Comment: Goddamn stupid thing goes in the script arguments slot without the "<". Then it works.

Answer (score 0):

This function determines if you are running under Windows or something else,
and makes the platform appropriate call. This answer is verbose to clearly illustrate the code flow in the function.

```
import sys
import os
import platform

# Accept either piped input or console input
# from either Windows or Other (Linux)

def get_input():
    system = platform.system()

    return_text = ""

    if system == 'Windows':
        return_text = input("Enter Text: ")  # Prompt user for input 
    else:
        return_text = sys.stdin.read()

    return return_text
```