# Input cin params into VisualStudio program

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cin

I am using Visual Studio and I want to run a simple program that uses `cin` to read input parameters

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n, k;
    cin >> n >> k;
    cout << n << k;
    return 0;
}
```

Now I want to run the program passing this two parameters.
I usually run by pressing Ctrl+Alt+N or just right clicking and selecting Run but I don't see how can I input my parameters.

When I run, VisualStudio basically does:

```
cd "/home/user/codeforce/" && g++ 977A.cpp -o 977A && "/home/user/codeforce/"977A
```

Is there a way to input parameters so they are read by cin?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [debugging with visual studio using redirected standard input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043986/debugging-with-visual-studio-using-redirected-standard-input)

Answer (score 0):

Start from the top: Press CTRL + f5 to run the program. A prompt will ask you if you want to Save\Build the project. Click 'yes' to both. A console window will appear, and based on your code, it will just be blank with a flashing cursor waiting for you to enter your values for `n` and `k`. Keep in mind that your code will take values for both `n` and `k` at the same time if you have any spaces, so if you input

```
10 45
```

the  output will be

```
1045
```

Answer (score 0):

The default keyboard shortcut `Ctrl + Alt + N` in Visual Studio corresponds to `TSqlEditorCloneQuery`.

I suggest you could follow the following steps to build and run your code in Visual Studio:

1,To build your project, choose `Build Solution` from the Build menu. The Output window shows the results of the build process.

[image]

2,To run the code, on the menu bar, choose `Debug`, `Start without debugging`.

[image]

A console window opens and then runs your app. When you start a console app in Visual Studio, it runs your code, And then you could enter values for `n` and `k`.

Answer (score -1):

Personally I do not use VisualStudio because it is very complicated compared to other editors, such as Atom or even command line editors such as vim. I did a quick research and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298708/debugging-with-command-line-parameters-in-visual-studio).

*Properties -> Debugging -> Command Arguments*

Comment: Command-line arguments are a different from streams, such as `std::cin`. Hence, your answer, doesn't, directly, answer the question, of "_Is there a way to input parameters so they are read by cin?_"