# how to wait for input at end when running / debugging c++ in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, input

I am looking to compete in the Google KickStart programming competition. I am using C++ in Visual Studio. (**not** visual studio code) Input parameters are given here as Console arguments, where they can be read with std::cin.

I want to paste the test input parameters into a text file and have the IDE pass them to the program as console arguments (held in the cin buffer). I have done this as defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043986/debugging-with-visual-studio-using-redirected-standard-input)

But with this method **the command line window will close immediately** after the program finishes instead of asking for any key to be pressed. I have tried waiting for dummy input but this does not fix the closing error

Comment: well command line arguments are NOT read via cin, so which is it args or cin?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I'm new to C++. Would it be right to call them console arguments?

Comment: ok, now i see this is a completely different question. Sorry. YOu need to add something at the end of the program to wait for input. like cin >> foo

Comment: You could start your program from command line.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I have been doing that. While having the solution is best, it is acceptable to run from command line

Answer (score 0):

You may easily implement your own wait "Press enter to continue..." at the end of your routine for testing.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
...
    int _tmp;
    std::cout << "Press enter to continue..." << std::endl;
    std::cin >> _tmp;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably your linker settings are incorrect. As far as I'm concerned you should set up `SubSystem` to `Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)`.(**Properties -> Linker -> System -> SubSystem**)