# Command Line Arguments for Visual Studio?

Tags: c++

```
#include "BBoard.h"
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    BBoard board;
    string name;
    name = argv[1];
    //const char * cstr_s = name.c_str();
    board.setup(name);
    board.login();
}
```

for my main cpp file, I am trying to use a command line argument by bringing in user1.txt.  In the debugging properties, I set it to C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\New folder\user1.txt but the command prompt window just flashes the underscore and does nothing.  Am I implementing the setting for the argument wrong?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298708/debugging-with-command-line-parameters-in-visual-studio)

Comment: how does ./a.out user1.txt work in the debugging pane?

Comment: If I understand what you are wanting to do, you should just have to put `user1.txt` (or the full filepath, if that's what your code expects) in the arguments text area as indicated in the linked question's answer, and it will be passed to your program as the argument(s) when you do a debug run through VS. What your program does with that argument is a different matter. Are you running your compiled program from the command prompt or via VS?

Comment: I am running it via ctrl f5 in VS.

Comment: Ctrl+F5 is `Start Without Debugging` (I'm using VS2010 Ultimate), which may not be using the arguments configured in the project's debug arguments properties. Try running with just F5 (which is `Start Debugging`) and see if it uses the arguments you've configured in the project properties.

Comment: My .exe crashed so I guess that there is something wrong with my code somewhere.

Comment: wkernel32.dll is not loaded according to the message

Comment: I'm not sure how to help debug that without more information (Google didn't have much that seemed immediately relevant). You might want to post a separate question with a copy of the full error message and details.