# debug C++ through Python

Tags: python, c++

I am calling an executable through a Python subprocess and would like to be able to debug the C++ code behind the exe. The C++ code and Python code are open in two Visual Studio instances. I have tried attaching the C++ to the Python Visual Studio so that the break points get hit when I run the Python subprocess code, but that doesn't seem to work. Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: You can attach the debugger to the running process, but I would probably just try to launch the program in the debugger with the same input as comes from python.

Comment: Attaching the debugger to the C++ is the best thing to do, but give us some context - does it crash straight away so you don't get a chance? What's going wrong? Does the C++ run OK when you manually run it from a command line?

Comment: The C++ is working fine from command line but not through Python subprocess. The process gets started but fails immediately with an error that seems odd, that's why I would like to debug it. Would I have to attach VS to the Python code or the command window that appears when I run the Python code?

Comment: How do you know it gets started? What error do you get? Can you post the python code? Can you make python start something else, e.g. just notepad?

Answer (score 0):

Can you modify the Python script to run your C++ code in this way?

```
devenv /debugexe 'program name' 'program arguments'
```

- from https://stackoverflow.com/a/417758/1190965