# Microsoft C# Tutorial Hello world "You entered the following {0} command line arguments"

Tags: c#

nice to meet you.
I'm new user of C# Language, and studying microsoft C# tutorial.
Link : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288436(v=vs.71).aspx

But I have a problem in the first lesson.
Link : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288463(v=vs.71).aspx

```
// Hello3.cs
// arguments: A B C D
using System;

public class Hello3
{
   public static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
      Console.WriteLine("You entered the following {0} command line arguments:", args.Length );
      for (int i=0; i < args.Length; i++)
      {
         Console.WriteLine("{0}", args[i]); 
      }
   }
}
```

And example output is this.

```
Hello, World!
You entered the following 4 command line arguments:
A
B
C
D
```

I don't know how to change the signature of the Main method.
How can I change this code to get example output?

---

+
My output is this.

```
Hello, World!
You entered the following 0 command line arguments:
```

It's all.

Comment: Why do you have to change anything?

Comment: change it to do `what`?  it should produce that output as is

Comment: @OldProgrammer Thank you for your reply. I added my output.  Check it please.

Comment: @Plutonix Thank you for your reply. I added my output. Check it please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method signature has already been changed to support that Main method's body.  The method states for each string passed in the string array of arguments, print the count, then each item passed in.

You can get that literal output by executing the application via command line and passing in A B C D.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288457(v=vs.71).aspx for a tutorial on passing command arguments to your application.

In your case it could be:

> Hello3.exe A B C D

Answer (score 1):

You don't. There are only two versions of `Main`: one which ignores the command-line arguments and one which receives them. You are using the latter. In order for the code to print A B C D, you need to invoke your program like this:

```
Hello3.exe A B C D
```

Alternately you can fake the command-line arguments with Visual Studio as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298708/debugging-with-command-line-parameters-in-visual-studio).

Comment: This is wrong. There are more than two. There are 4. void Main(), void Main(string[]), int Main() and int Main(string[])

Comment: @L33TS Fair enough, I ignored the return value...

Comment: Don't sweat it mate! :)