# put a file in argv[] of main function

Tags: c, argv

hi I'm trying to write a program like this in visual C++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *in;
    char ch;
    int openbracket=0,closebracket=0;

    if(argc!=2)
    {
        printf("the number of arguments is incorrect");
        getch();
        exit(1);
    }

    if((in=fopen(arg[1],"r"))==NULL)
    {
        fputs("Error",stderr);  exit(1);
    }

    ch=getc(in);

    while(!feof(in))
    {

        if(ch=='{')
            openbracket++;

        else if(ch=='}')
            closebracket++;

        ch=getc(in);
    }

    printf("Open bracket==%d,close bracket=%d",openbracket,closebracket);

    getch();

}
```

i am trying to open a file with argv[1] in this program in visual c++
can you please show me how i can put a file in argv[1] 0f main function?

Thank you

Comment: What problems or difficulties are you encountering?

Comment: Are you using C or C++?  This code looks like C.  If you are being taught this is C++ then you might want to look for a new place to learn C++.

Comment: When you compile this program, you are getting an error message.  ***Shame*** on you for not putting the error message in your question.

Answer (score 2):

```
if((in=fopen(arg[1],"r"))==NULL);
```

1. if-statements do **NOT** end with a semi-colon. That makes this a "do-nothing" statement
2. `arg` is never declared anywhere (you have declared `argc` and `argv`, but not `arg`)

Comment: my problem is not this I want to pass a text file in argv[1]

Comment: Your code will not even compile as is.  You must fix compile errors before you can work on proper behavior.

Comment: Is this the question you really mean to be asking?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298708/debugging-with-command-line-parameters-in-visual-studio