# Are there a built-in terminal like Android Studio inside the Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, command-line, terminal

I am trying OpenCV with VS2017. But I want to use command prompt to build&run my projects. Because I can use "argv[1]" argument simply to pass images trough my apps. But I don't know how can I do it? Inside the Linux it was easy and I could do it by using these commands:

```
g++ name_of_app.cpp -o name_of_app

./name_of_app "/home/path_to_image"
```

Are there a way to accessing the terminal from inside the Visual Studio 2017?

Comment: In your solution's properties, you can select `Debug -> Command line arguments`.

Comment: @Phylogenesis: may you put a screenshot of that?

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298708/debugging-with-command-line-parameters-in-visual-studio).

Comment: So there is no built-in terminal like what we have inside the android studio inside the visual studio? And we should put out arguments inside that table graphically?