# What is the successor debugging configuration file location of vcxproj.user since Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, vssettings

For older versions of Visual Studio the debugging properties - which you can [configure in the IDE under Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298708/debugging-with-command-line-parameters-in-visual-studio) - were stored in the corresponding *vcxproj.user* file. Since Visual Studio 2015 there is no *vcxproj.user* file any more. Into which file has this information been moved in order to set these properties (e.g. *Command Arguments*) outside the IDE (e.g. for batching purposes)?

Comment: I am using MSVC 2017, yet still have *.vcxproj.user file. Checked on the project I had created three days ago.

Comment: In my case there is no *.vcxproj.user file for VS 2015 any more, but Debugging properties are permantly stored somewhere since they reappear in the IDE throughout the days ;-)